# NSPredicate by string values from array

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate

how to write NSPredicate to fetch all values that not equals ID's from array

here is how im trying to do this:

```
var mediaArr: [String] = ["1002971147784767054_3158228926", "1002971147784767054_3158228976", "1002971147784767054_3158228986"]
let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Orders", predicate: NSPredicate(format: "mediaId != %@", self.mediaArr))
```

Comment: Did you try? -NSPredicate(format: "NOT(mediaId  IN %@)", self.mediaArr))

Comment: @Shripada yeap it works now

Answer (score 2):

solved with

```
let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Orders", predicate: NSPredicate(format: "NOT (mediaId IN %@)", self.mediaArr))
```